# Is there a method for separating a logged in user from a super user in the views.py of a django based website?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I created a blog and users have to create an account to have access to make comment. My question is how do i make logged in users have a different access from to super user who can create a blog posts? I need a way to restrict general logged in users so they don't have similar access from the Super users.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlMoK.png)

I tried using using if user.is_superuser in one of the html pages i want to restrict but it is still not working[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xU0z.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **DO NOT** attach images of code. They cannot be copy/pasted, indexed by search engines, and can be blocked by filters. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add your code as formatted text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.user.is_superuser` to check if a user is a superuser in a template:

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```